# How to prevent not to rebuild UI inside Index Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I'm using index stack in home screen to show different screen at one time.

My problem is that child widget is rebuilt again and make API call when ever I re-enter to any screen.

Home screen code:

```
final _currentPage =
        context.select<MenuProvider, int>((provider) => provider.currentPage);

    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
      Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateCurrentPage(index);
    }

    List<MenuItem> mainMenu = [
      MenuItem(
        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sd_title,
        'Home',
        Icons.home,
        0,
      ),
      MenuItem(
        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.profile_title,
        'Profile',
        Icons.person,
        1,
      ),
      MenuItem(
        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sd_calculator,
        'Calculator',
        Icons.calculate_rounded,
        2,
      ),
    ];

    var screens = [
      mainMenu[_currentPage].index == 0 ? const HomeFragment() : Container(),
      mainMenu[_currentPage].index == 1 ? const Profile() : Container(),
      mainMenu[_currentPage].index == 2
          ? LoanCalculatorScreen(isHome: true)
          : Container(),
    ];

    var container = Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: FadeIndexedStack(
        index: mainMenu[_currentPage].index,
        children: screens,
      ),
    );
```

Container is used in body of Scaffold.

Bottom Navigation:

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: mainMenu
            .map(
              (item) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: item.bottomTitle,
                icon: Icon(
                  item.icon,
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        currentIndex: _currentPage,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      )
```

Home screen: As statefull to make a call on init state;

```
@override
  void initState() {
    var homeData = Provider.of<HomeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    homeData.getOffersAndPartnersSlider();

    super.initState();
  }
```

I'm using Provider for state management and API call.

Any suggestion will help me to write better code and make good performance.

I've tred page view also same  thing happen the inside child is rebuilt.

I just want to make The API call once.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I've made changes with Pages.

Declare list of pages above built method with PageStorageKey.

```
   final List<Widget> pages = [
        const HomeFragment(
          key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
        ),
        const Profile(
          key: PageStorageKey('Page2'),
        ),
        Lo

LoanCalculatorScreen(key: const PageStorageKey('Page'), isHome: true),
  ];
```

And Call pages inside Indexed Stack Widgets Children

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: FadeIndexedStack(
          index: mainMenu[_currentPage].index,
          children: pages,
        ),
      )
```